# Java 9 changed default title height of JFrame after resizing is disabled

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-9

My Swing application cannot get consistent appearance between Java 8 and Java 9. It doesn't use a layout manager, so that all components are given exact size, but I found that running with Java 9, title of JFrame gets a different height and the status bar is not fully rendered. Please refer to the attached screen dump; it seems it is a bug.

I also studied how to repeat it with a simple demo program and found that it is not related to a layout manager. It seems that problem occurs after resizing is disabled. Please try the attached demo source code.

I also tried the following parameters, but they don't help:

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0
-Dprism.allowhidpi=false
```

My system runs Windows 10 1709 / Java 9.0.4:

```
D:\JavaEnv\J2SE9.X64\bin>java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

D:\JavaEnv\J2SE9.X64\bin>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371]
```

Screen dump:

[image: Different title height with Java 9]

Sample program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class FirstFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FirstFrame()
    {
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();

        getContentPane().add(new JTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JToolBar statusbar = new JToolBar();

        statusbar.add(new JLabel("Status:"));
        getContentPane().add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(menu);

        super.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        super.setTitle("Default Frame");

        // It seems that problem is here.
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setResizable(false);

        super.setLocation(100, 100);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        new FirstFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: The best is probably that you provide an [mcve] that shows the difference between the two.

Comment: `It doesn't use layout manager,` - and that is the problem. The point of using a layout manager is that the layout manager will adapt across platforms and versions. For example, different platforms/versions could use a different font causing slight differences. so the solution to your problem is to fix the code and use Swing the way it was designed to be used, which means use layout managers. Based on the picture provided there is absolutely no reason for you to use a null layout.

Comment: @Didier L , Attached demo source code. it seems that it is related to JFrame.setResizing(false).

Comment: @camickr  , after compared with Java 9,  case 1 (call frame.setResizing(false))  & case 2 (don't call frame.setResizing(false))  get different frame sizes,  not between Java 8 vs. Java 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is confirmed as a bug by the Java bug system at:

[JDK-8202015: JFrame.setResizable(false) gives different frame size & title height from Java 8](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202015)

Let's wait for the bugfix.